# In Python, what determines the order while iterating through kwargs?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

In python, I wrote this function to teach myself how `**kwargs` works in Python:

```
def fxn(a1, **kwargs):
    print a1
    for k in kwargs:
        print k, " : ", kwargs[k]
```

I then called this function with

```
fxn(3, a2=2, a3=3, a4=4)
```

Here was the output that my Python interpreter printed:

```
3
a3  :  3
a2  :  2
a4  :  4
```

Why did the for loop print the value of a3 before that of a2 even though I fed a2 into my function first?

Comment: I suggest marking @afxentios's answer as Accepted instead. (I'd be concerned about offending the previous answer winner, but their account seems to have been deleted.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`kwargs` is a dictionary. Dictionaries are unordered - simply put, the order is unspecified and an implementation detail. Peeking under the hood will show that the order varies wildly depending on the hash values of the items, the order of insertion, etc. so you better don't rely on anything related to it.

Comment: Didn't it change in recent version of python ?

Comment: @AdrienH: It did, in 3.6, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634018/364696).

Answer (score 11):

This is a dictionary. And, as mentioned in documentation, **dictionary has no order** (from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered set of key: value pairs**, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

But you can **make it processed in some order**, like that:

- using `sorted()`:

  ```
  def fxn(a1, **kwargs):
      print a1
      for k in sorted(kwargs): # notice "kwargs" replaced by "sorted(kwargs)"
          print k, " : ", kwargs[k]
  ```
- or by using `OrderedDict` type (you can pass `OrderedDict` object as parameter containing all the key-value pairs):

  ```
  from collections import OrderedDict

  def fxn(a1, ordkwargs):
      print a1
      for k in ordkwargs:
          print k, " : ", ordkwargs[k]

  fxn(3, OrderedDict((('a2',2), ('a3',3), ('a4',4))))
  ```

Comment: See my answer with regard to OrderedDict.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: See my comment to your answer.

Comment: Wouldn't you write that as `fxn(3, **OrderedDict(etc...`? Oh wait, I see that you changed the signature to take a dict, not a set of keyword arguments. If you are going to change the signature, then you might as well just pass a list of your key-value tuples. But the OP really wanted to iterate over **kwargs.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: I explicitly stated, that `kwargs` **has no order**, thus I proposed alternative solutions: 1) iterating through ordered `kwargs`, and 2) passing `OrderedDict` istead of using keyword arguments. Yes, you can pass the tuples, but if you pass tuples, you won't be able to use it like `dict` or `OrderedDict`, would you? :) If you use my second solution, the body of the function does not change much (as it would have to be changed in case of tuples passed in the argument). Compare `dict` vs. `OrderedDict` vs. `tuple` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 11):

This has finally been introduced in the [3.6 release](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep468): `dict`s are now ordered, therefore the keyword argument order is preserved.

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 13 2017, 13:27:48) 
>>> def print_args(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs.keys())
... 
>>> print_args(first=1, second=2, third=3)
dict_keys(['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

Comment: `**kwargs` aren't an `OrderedDict` in Python 3.6. They continue to be a `dict`, but now `dict` is ordered.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

The unfortunate irony is that the dict-ification of **kwargs means that the following will not work (at least not the way one would expect):

```
od = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Since the keyworded args are first built into an unordered dict, you cannot depend that they will be inserted into the OrderedDict in the order they are listed. :(

Comment: But the following will: `od = OrderedDict((('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3)))`. So basically `**kwargs`, because it is a `dict`, will not have any order, but you can always pass `OrderedDict` as parameter, and it will have the order you want it to have.

Answer (score 2):

Since `kwargs` is a Python **dictionary**, which is implemented as a [**hash table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), its ordering is not preserved and is effectively random.

Actually, as a fix to a recent [security issue](https://lwn.net/Articles/474912/) in many programming languages, in the future the order may even change between invocations of your program (invocations of the Python interpreter).

Comment: Not random - in fact, it's totally determinate. Just not easily predictable, as it depends on the hash.

Comment: You're of course right. That is the reason I said "effectively random", to indicate to the reader the he should not attempt to guess it. On a side note, almost everything a computer does is determinate but may not be easily predictable :)

Answer (score 1):

`kwargs` is a dictionary, in Python these are not ordered so the result is essentially (pseudo-) random.