# The order of print when use items() in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I write a function like this in python:

```
def test(**argv):
    for k,v in argv.items():
        print k,v
```

and use the function like this:

```
test(x = 1, y=2, z=3)
```

The printout is this:

```
y 2
x 1
z 3
```

I was wondering why the result of printout is not?:

```
x 1
y 2
z 3
```

Any help here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, what determines the order while iterating through kwargs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977594/in-python-what-determines-the-order-while-iterating-through-kwargs)

Comment: @ jonrsharpe whoops, sorry what should I do now?

Comment: Read the linked question, delete yours if you agree it's answered there, otherwise wait for the community to vote to decide what should happen. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: @jonrsharpe It says that Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead

Comment: Ok, just wait and see!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you print the **type** of `argv`, you will realize it is a dictionary.

Dictionaries are unordered in Python. That's why you get that output.

**Test**

```
def test(**argv):
    print type(argv)

test()

>>> <type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is a hash table, the order of the keys is not guaranteed. You you need to preserve the order - there is [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which preserves the order of element addition.

Comment: Can you make `**kwargs` use OrderedDict? I think you'd need a post-hoc `sort`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Correct. You can sort the key value pairs, but even that way you can't retrieve the order the keyword arguments were written out at the call site.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yep, the order is not preserved if ordered dictionary is passed as keyword argument.