# lxml preserves attributes order?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, minidom

I was writing my aplication using minidom but minidom does not preserve attribute order(sorts alphabetically), so I decided to do it using lxml.

However in the following lines of code I'm not getting the desired order:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
SATNS = "link_1"
NS = "link_2"
location_attribute = '{%s}schemaLocation' % NS
root = ET.Element('{%s}Catalogo' % SATNS, nsmap={'catalogocuentas':SATNS}, attrib=
   {location_attribute: 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas'}, Ano="2014",       Mes="02",   TotalCtas="219", RFC="ALF040329CX6", Version="1.0")
print (ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

This is what I'm expecting to get:

```
<catalogocuentas:Catalogo xmlns:catalogocuentas="link_1"
xmlns:xsi="link_2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas"
Ano="2014" Mes="02" TotalCtas="219" RFC="XXX010101XXX" Version="1.0">
</catalogocuentas:Catalogo>
```

Which is in the order that I filled in:

```
root=ET.element(...)
```

But I'm getting the next, that has no order:

```
<catalogocuentas:Catalogo xmlns:catalogocuentas="link_1" 
xmlns:xsi="link_2" RFC="ALF040329CX6" Version="1.0" 
Mes="02" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas" Ano="2014" TotalCtas="219">
</catalogocuentas:Catalogo>
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to give `lxml` a custom dictionary type to use for attribute dictionaries, so you could pass it `collections.OrderedDict`. However, as Patrick Collins's answer explains, this is almost definitely a bad idea. (IIRC, you do it by either subclassing the default parser class, or creating an instance of the default class and setting a member on it, then either way passing it as the `parser=` argument to the `Element` constructor, the `parse` function, or whatever else you start off with.

Comment: That being said, if you want it to preserve order, you have to give it the attributes in order in the first place, and keyword arguments to a function are arbitrarily ordered. (See [PEP 468](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0468/) for an open proposal to change that, but it seems to be stalled, even though Guido and the core devs were relatively open to the idea after a bit of discussion…)

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - lxml: enforcing an specific order for attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917943/python-lxml-enforcing-an-specific-order-for-attributes)

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries in Python are [unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so). Keyword arguments are passed to functions by a dictionary traditionally named `**kwargs`, and so [the order is lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977594/in-python-what-determines-the-order-while-iterating-through-kwargs). The function can't possibly know what order the arguments to `ET.element` came in.

As stated [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917943/python-lxml-enforcing-an-specific-order-for-attributes), there isn't really any way to get this done. XML doesn't care about attribute order, so there isn't really any good reason to do it.

Comment: I totally agree with you, the question here is that I need to send my XML to a XML validator that doesn't accept my XML if it's not in the order defined that I'm trying to reach

Comment: @DiegoCalzadilla The XML validator has a (very serious) bug, you should file a report with whoever maintains it.

Comment: @DiegoCalzadilla From the third question I linked: "As far as I know, lxml has no mechanism for specifying the order attributes appear in serialized XML, and I would be surprised if it did."

Comment: @DiegoCalzadilla It looks like html5lib might have what you want: https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/issues/37