# lxml order of attributes

Tags: python, xml, lxml, minidom

As stated in this question:

[lxml preserves attributes order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518415/lxml-preserves-attributes-order)

And taking the @abarnet suggestion I wrote the following line of code:

```
root = ET.Element('{%s}Catalogo' % SATNS, OrderedDict([("Ano","2014"),("Mes","02"),("TotalCtas","219"),("RFC","XXX010101XXX"),("Version","1.0")]), nsmap={'catalogocuentas':SATNS})
```

I get this:

```
<catalogocuentas:Catalogo xmlns:catalogocuentas="http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas" Ano="2014" Mes="02" TotalCtas="219" RFC="XXX010101XXX" Version="1.0"/>
```

which is great(it preserves the desired order), but when I want to add the missing information:

```
xmlns:xsi="link_2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas"
```

as part of my xml and then I add this info in my python code:

```
attrib={location_attribute: 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas'}
```

so that it becomes:

```
root = ET.Element('{%s}Catalogo' % SATNS, OrderedDict([("Ano","2014"),("Mes","02"),("TotalCtas","219"),("RFC","XXX010101XXX"),("Version","1.0")]), nsmap={'catalogocuentas':SATNS}, attrib={location_attribute: 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas'})
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2558, in lxml.etree.Element (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:52829)
TypeError: Element() got multiple values for keyword argument 'attrib'
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are sending the `Element()` init method the same keyword argument twice. For your initialization your second argument is being used as the `attrib` keyword. Which in this instance is your `OrderedDict()` which contains all your attributes. You then try to supply it again which is where it runs into a collision. You can remedy this one of two ways:

You can add this attribute to your attribute `OrderedDict()` like so:

```
root = ET.Element('{%s}Catalogo' % SATNS, OrderedDict([("Ano","2014"),("Mes","02"),("TotalCtas","219"),("RFC","XXX010101XXX"),("Version","1.0"),("location_attribute","http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas")]), nsmap={'catalogocuentas':SATNS})
```

Alternatively you could add it on the next line as well by doing this:

```
root.attrib["location_attribute"] = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/catalogocuentas"
```